# selectize js - return key [⏎] delimiter for multiselect / tagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Is there a way to use the <kbd>⏎</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as delimiter for a selectize multiselect field?
Unfortunately I could not find anything about the delimiter at all, either in the docs nor via Google (explicitly for my case).

The default settings should look like this:

```
$('#input-tags').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
```

So it seems that only regular chars are allowed?!

Comment: Maybe try `\n` or `\r\n` in the `delimiter`. It depends how the value is used to `split()`. It may also be worth checking the plugin documentation

Comment: I've added it as an answer for you now. I only did it as a comment previously as I wasn't familiar with the library you're using to know if was a definite solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rory's answer will work however it will not prevent auto-completion on enter. To ensure you always get a new item on enter use the plugin

```
Selectize.define('enter_key_delim', function (options) {
    var self = this

    this.onKeyDown = (function (e) {
    var original = self.onKeyDown
    return function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            self.createItem();
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return original.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
    })()
})
```

Then in your options for the selectize element use `plugins: ['enter_key_delim']`,

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer in my opinion, the other one didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin builds a Regular Expression to use in the `split()` method you should be able to provide `\r` or `\r\n` to the `delimiter` property, like this:

```
delimiter: '\r\n'
```